# Why do we use spinal-case for directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
When we talk about directives, we’ll use lowerCamelCase method (e.g. ngClick) 
to refer to the directive. This is because in the AngularJS source code it is 
defined as a function called ngClick. However, when we use a directive in HTML 
we use “kabob case” (e.g. ng-click). Basically: ngClick and ng-click refer 
to the same thing, AngularJS automatically converts between the two. It can be a 
little confusing at first, but the idea is that it makes each code look better in 
context.
```

This is what was given in http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/how-to-learn-angular.html
while explaining about directives in AngularJS.

When `ngClick` and `ng-click` refer to the same thing **could we** use this approach?

```
<button ngClick="runWhenButtonClicked()">Click me</button>
```

instead of this approach

```
<button ng-click="runWhenButtonClicked()">Click me</button>
```

**My question is, is it a rule to use spinal-case or can we use camelCase too?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

camelCase directive in your partial won't even work so `<button ngClick="runWhenButtonClicked()">Click me</button>` doesn't do anything.

Angular does a translation, so the defenition of your directive is always camelCased whereas using the directive is always spinal-cased.

try it: http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/2nH4f/

In the definition:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective1', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>I was used spinal-cased</span>'
    };
});

myApp.directive('myDirective2', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>I was used camelCased</span>'
    };
});
```

In the partial:

```
<div my-directive1>i'm not replaced.</div>
<div myDirective2>i'm not replaced.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Angular uses spinal-case for its custom attributes and camelCase for
>   the corresponding directives which implement them

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00#what-is-the-code-doing-